# Max number pool input text from database and decrease it when pick to form html/js/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok i have a little code to distribute point from pool in to stats made with form. my Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mynindo.pl/test/css/style.css">

  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="http://mynindo.pl/test/js/incrementing.js"></script>
 <link href="http://mynindo.pl/test/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 </head>
<body>
<div class="well">
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="">Points: 50<br /><br />
      
        <label for="name">Int</label>
        <div class="numbers-row"><input type="text" name="int" id="int" value="0">
      </div>

        <label for="name">Str</label>
              <div class="numbers-row"><input type="text" name="men" id="men" value="0">
      </div>
        <label for="name">Dex</label>
              <div class="numbers-row"><input type="text" name="dex" id="dex" value="0">
      </div>
        <label for="name">Dex2</label>
              <div class="numbers-row"><input type="text" name="str" id="str" value="0">
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
      </div>
    </form>


</div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

My php code in app.php check if sum of all points $Post[] is == points pool. every works fine, but wieh user got meny poits for the distribute need math so can't be tricky.

And now my question, is this possible to change value of poits pool in real time with ajax or jquery? i mean, i got 50 points total i add 1 to Str (didn;t sumbit) and value pool changed from 50 to 49 w/o reloading page?

Answer (score 0):

as you are not updating database until pressing submit button then just manipulating that span element will suffice, 
put following code your html section instead of your corresponding code

```
Points: <span id="point" data-available="50">50</span>
```

Add following JavaScript code

```
$(':text').change(function(){
  var total=0;
    $( ":text" ).each(function( i ) {
     total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  $('#point').html($('#point').data("available")-total);
});
```

this will do the trick.

**BTW** you should make sure input is number

Answer (score 0):

I Tried to add Uoyr code reza but i'm not sure how, also i tried wrote my own script to count all those numbers but it also fail

```
function countNum(val) {
    var sum = document.getElementById("sum").value;
    var i = document.getElementById("int").value;
    var w = document.getElementById("men").value;
    var s = document.getElementById("dex").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("str").value;
    var points = i + w + s + d;
    if ( points == 0){
    $('#suma').text(0);
    }else{
    $('#suma').text(suma - points);
    }};
```

with

`Points: <div style="display: inline;" id="sum">50</div>`

But didn't work at all. Cna you show me how ur code should work with my on snippet?